Find $\mathbb{W} \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ such that both of the following conditions are satisfied
Let $\mathbb{S} = \langle (1,0,2,1), (0,1,1,0) \rangle$ and $\mathbb{T} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 0, x_1 + x_2 = 0\}$.
Find if it exists, a subspace $\mathbb{W} \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ such that both of the following conditions are satisfied simultaneously:
$\mathbb{S} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{S} + \mathbb{T}$ and $\mathbb{T} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{S} + \mathbb{T}$
What I have done:
$\textbf{I found a basis for T:}$
$\begin{cases} 
x_1 = -x_2  \\ x_4 = -2x_2 - x_3
\end{cases}$
$t \in \mathbb{T}$
$t = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (-x_2, x_2, x_3, -2x_2 - x_3)$
$t = (-x_2, x_2, x_3, -2x_2 - x_3) = x_2(-1,1,0,-2) + x_3(0,0,1,-1)$
$\mathbb{T} = \langle (-1,1,0,-2), (0,0,1,-1) \rangle$
$\textbf{I tried to calculate }$ $\mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{T}$
$s \in \mathbb{S}$
$s = a(1,0,2,1) + b(0,1,1,0)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$
$s = (a,0,2a,a) + (0,b,b,0) = (a,b,2a+b,a)$ now I make this vector $s$ satisfy the equations of the plane $\mathbb{T}$
$\mathbb{T} : \begin{cases} x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 + x_4 &= 0 \\ x_1 + x_2 &= 0 \end{cases}$
$\mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{T} : \begin{cases} a + 3b + 2a + b + a &= 0 \\ a + b &= 0 \implies a = -b\end{cases}$
$(a,b,c,d) = (-b,b,-2b+b, -b) = (-b,b,-b,-b)$
$\mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{T} = b(-1,1,-1,-1)$ with $b \in \mathbb{R}$
$\mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{T}$ = $\langle(-1,1,-1,-1)\rangle$
$\textbf{One idea I have:}$
from the dimension theorem of finite vector spaces
$\dim(\mathbb{S} + \mathbb{T})$ = $\dim(\mathbb{S}) + \dim(\mathbb{T}) - \dim(\mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{T})$
since is a direct sum
$\dim(\mathbb{S} \oplus \mathbb{W}) = \dim(\mathbb{S}) + \dim(\mathbb{W})$
so
$\dim(\mathbb{S}) + \dim(\mathbb{W}) = \dim(\mathbb{S}) + \dim(\mathbb{T}) - \dim(\mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{T})$
if we subtract $\dim(\mathbb{S})$ in both sides
$\dim(\mathbb{W}) = \dim(\mathbb{T}) - \dim(\mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{T})$
so
$\dim(\mathbb{W}) = 2 - 1 = 1$

Let $s =(0,1,1,0) \in S $, $t = (0,0,1,-1) \in T$ and $w=s+t= (0,1,2,-1)$.
I claim that $\mathbb{W}=\left\langle w \right \rangle$ is a desired subspace. Indeed, if $\mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{S} \supsetneq \left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace$, there exists a nonzero $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $cw = cs+ct \in \mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{S}$. But this implies that
$$ ct = cw-cs \in \mathbb{S}$$
On the other hand, it is obvious that $ct \in \mathbb{T}$, thus $ct \in \mathbb{S}\cap  \mathbb{T}$, which is impossible as $t \notin \langle(-1,1,-1,-1)\rangle$. Hence $\mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{S} = \left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace$.  It is also clear that $\mathbb{W} \subset \mathbb{S}+\mathbb{T}$. By dimension counting, you have that $\dim \mathbb{S} + \dim \mathbb{W} = \dim (\mathbb{S}+\mathbb{T})=3$. Combining with  $\mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{S} = \left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace$, we can deduce that
$$\mathbb{S} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{S}+\mathbb{T}$$
In the same way, you can show that $\mathbb{W} \cap \mathbb{T} = \left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace$ and $\mathbb{T} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \mathbb{S}+\mathbb{T}$.
As hinted in the comment, there are various choices of $s,t$ as long as you ensured $s,t \notin \mathbb{S} \cap \mathbb{T}$.
